# Надо синонимизировать [import] -> [импорт]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Метки [import](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import) (343 вопроса) и [импорт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82) (63 вопроса) по-моему об одном и том же. Надо их синонимизировать.

Comment: Надеюсь, вы ещё не устали от моих постоянных предложений по синонимизации меток?

Comment: Пока нет. Ведь кто ещё будет это предлагать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 395 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 342 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 335 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'import': [import] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 398
tag remapping of [импорт] and [import] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
90 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym import -> импорт was approved!
```

Comment: А почему этот вывод на английском?

Comment: @nchistov видимо, решили не заморачиваться с локализацией логов, видимых только модератору.

Comment: Наверное так и есть.